# PHP if strange behaviour

Tags: php, sugarcrm

I have a very strange behaviour. I'm working on a framework written in php (CRM Sugar). Here is a block of code inside a logic hook:

```
var_dump($cbs->userCanUpdateOrder()); // ==> OUTSIDE THE IF BLOCK bool(true)
exit(1); 

if( $cbs->userCanUpdateOrder() == false ) (same with ! )
{
  var_dump($cbs->userCanUpdateOrder()); //INSIDE THE IF BLOCK bool(false)
  exit(1); 

}

if( $cbs->userCanUpdateOrder() == true ) 
{
  var_dump($cbs->userCanUpdateOrder());//// INSIDE THE BLOCK bool(true)
  exit(1); 

}
```

The block is always executed with true or false condition! perhaps I'm a bit tired in this moment, but I'm stuck. So any ideas?

for completeness here is the full (real) code inside before_relationship_add/delete logic hook :

```
public function checkCandidateForOrder( $bean, $event, $arguments )
    {
      global $current_user; 
      $candidate = null;
      $order = null;
      $errorM = null;

      // Assure that we are on subpanel action: 
      // Delete Or Add 
      if( (isset($_REQUEST['subpanel_module_name']) && $_REQUEST['subpanel_module_name']== 'adu4_ordini_adhr_candidati_1') || isset( $_REQUEST['ajaxSubpanel'] ) && $_REQUEST['action']=='DeleteRelationship' )
      {   

        $candidate = BeanFactory::getBean( $arguments['related_module'], $arguments['related_id'] );

        $order = BeanFactory::getBean( $arguments['module'], $arguments['id'] );

        $url = 'index.php?module='.$_REQUEST['module'].'&action=DetailView&record='.$_REQUEST['record'];

        $cbs = new CandidateBookingService($current_user,$candidate,$order,true); 


        if( !$cbs->userCanUpdateOrder() )
        {
          $errorM = "alert message...";
          $url.="&errorM=".$errorM;
          if (headers_sent()) {
            echo "<script>SUGAR.ajaxUI.loadContent('$url');</script>\n";
          }else{   
            header('Location: ' . $url, true, 302 );
            exit(); // do not permit to update the action and flush
          }
        }

        if( $_REQUEST['action'] == 'DeleteRelationship' )
        {

          $cbs->removeCandidatesOrdersRelationship();
          if( $order->id == $candidate->ordered_by_id_c )
            $cbs->removeCandidateFromOrder();  
        }
        else{ // Add relationship:

          if($order->status_c != 'lost' )
            $cbs->addCandidatesOrdersRelationship();
          else{
            $errorM = "alert ...";
            $url.="&errorM=".$errorM;
            if (headers_sent()) {
              echo "<script>SUGAR.ajaxUI.loadContent('$url');</script>\n";
            }else{   
              header('Location: ' . $url, true, 302 );
              exit(); // do not permit to update the action and flush
            }          
          }
        }
      }
    }
```

Comment: Hi, I'm not sure I follow what is going on. In the first code snippet what is output of the first var_dump? Also what is the result when you remove the exit(1) on line 2? Which of the two if statements is executed?

Comment: What does the `userCanUpdateOrder()` method actually do? It's entirely possible that it could return a different result if called multiple times

Comment: "The block is always executed with true or false condition" <- which block? The minimal example includes an `exit` on line 2, so no line after that is reachable.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you to dk80 and Mark Baker. 
Inspired by your suggestions, I noticed that the block is executed (unexpectedly two times), because logically hooked with two consecutive events, related to  parts with different authorizations.

Best regards